# Removing Duplicate Rows of SQL Query using Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The SQL query below is producing duplicate rows.

Without using a `DISTINCT` clause, is it possible to remove these duplicates?

```
SELECT  RCY.Date,RCY.Period,RCY.Client,RCY.[Device Type],RCY.Metric,RCY.OS,RCY.Service,RCY.[User Type],RCY.Workload,RCY.Value,RCY.[Wow%],RCY.WoW - RPY.WoW AS YOY_WOW 
FROM   dbo.vw_Metric_WOW RCY LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_Metric_WOW RPY 
ON RCY.period = RPY.period 
AND RCY.metric = RPY.metric 
AND RCY.workload = RPY.workload 
AND RCY.client = RPY.client 
AND RCY.service = RPY.service 
AND RCY.os = RPY.os 
AND RCY.[device type] = RPY.[device type] 
AND RCY.[user type] = RPY.[user type] 
AND RPY.date = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, RCY.date)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, zzstar.  IT would help if you could edit your question to include a small set of sample data and a set that describe the output you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you are trying to get difference in "WoW" between 2 tables you have to use "INNER JOIN" or "ISNULL(RPY.WoW,0)"

Second, just try to do "SELECT *" for that query and in the result set look for "changing" values. That might give you a clue which else column(s) to add to JOIN.